# How to count the amount of integers in a textfile (Java)?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that counts the number of integers in a Java textfile. If there is an even number of integers, the program should read the integers in pairs and print out the maximum of the two numbers. For example if the textfile had the integers `6 2 5 9`, Java should print out `6 9`. If there is an odd amount of integers, it should print an error message.

I got the program to print out the max, but I cant figure out how to make it count the amount of integers. The program compiles, but runs a blank screen. What did I do wrong?

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1_Reading_Files {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("integers.txt"));
      int count = 0;
      int max = 0;
      int num1;
      int num2;
      while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
         count++;
      }
      if (count % 2 == 0) {
         while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            num1=reader.nextInt();
            num2=reader.nextInt();
            if (num1>num2){
               max=num1;
            }
            else if (num2>num1) {
               max=num2;
            }
            System.out.print(max+" ")
         }
      }
      else  {
         System.out.println("The File has an odd number of Integers");
      }          
   }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to reset the `Scanner` before you can re-read the file. You might consider doing it all within a single loop and discard the result when there an odd number of results

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by an "integer".  Is "63" one or two integers?  Is "1F" one integer or an integer and a letter?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
  while (reader.hasNextInt())  {        
     count++;
  }
```

If `reader.hasNextInt()` is true, it will be true forever and your program will never leave this loop...

A working version:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab1_Reading_Files       {

  public static void main (String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("integers.txt"));    
      int count=0;
      int max=0;
      int num1;
      int num2;   

      while (reader.hasNextInt())  {        
         num1=reader.nextInt();
         count++;
         if (!reader.hasNextInt()) {
             System.out.println("The File has an odd number of Integers");
             break;
         }
         num2=reader.nextInt(); 
         count++;        

         if (num1>num2) max = num1;
         else           max = num2;

         System.out.println(max + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("The file had " + count + " number(s)");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But what does the        break;       mean and what does it do?

Comment: Break means to jump out of the enclosing loop.